# Realizing different distribution models in hdfs?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

As far as i have got to understand from the hadoop tuitorial, it takes the overall size of  the input files and then divides them into the blocks/chunks then these block are replicated on different nodes.However i want to realize data distribution model according to the below given requirement -

(a) Case one : Each file is partitioned into the nodes in the cluster equally 
-- so that each map gets this partition of table to be accessed. is it possible ?

(b) Case two : Each file is fully replicated in two or more nodes but not all nodes.
so that each map access some part of table on each node. is it possible ?

Comment: Please go through the concepts in depth: Hadoop Definitive Guide is a very good reference.

Answer (score 1):

HDFS does not store tables, it stores files. Higher level projects offer 'relational tables', like Hive. Hive does allow you to partition a table stored on HDFS, see [Hive Tutorial](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Tutorial).

That being said, you should not tie partitioning to number of nodes in the cluster. Nodes come and go, clusters grow and shrink. Partitioned relational tables partition/bucket by natural boundaries w/o relation to cluster size. Import, export, daily operations all play a role in partitioning (and usually a much bigger role then cluster size). Even a single table (file) can well spread on each node of the cluster.

If you want to tune a MR job for optimal split size/location, there are plenty of ways to do that. You still have a lot to read, you are optimizing too early.

Comment: thanks Remus. i appreciate your response. actually all this is part of my academic assignment i am reading the tutorials.